# Use ajax in JavaScript geocoder

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try to make JavaScript after obtaining the address of the maps by latitude and longitude, send to another php the address by ajax.

But it doesn't work for me, it doesn't activate ajax. The truth is that I do not understand why this happens, both the ajax code and the JavaScript maps part, are independently tested and work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $long;?>);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    var Var_JavaScript = results[1].formatted_address;
                    window.location.replace("insert-fichaje2.php?lat=<?php echo $lat;?>&long=<?php echo $long;?>&status=<?php echo $status;?>&usuario=<?php echo $usuario;?>&direccion="+Var_JavaScript);

                }
            }

        });

</script>
```

If change `window.location.replace` for:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert-fichaje2.php?lat=<?php echo $lat;?>&long=<?php echo $long;?>&status=<?php echo $status;?>&usuario=<?php echo $usuario;?>&direccion="+Var_JavaScript ,
          dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
      alert(" Con exito");
       window.close();

    },
    error: function() {
      alert(" ERROR!!!");
    }

        });
```

then it is not working.

Error console:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
insert-fichaje.php?lat=40.394548&long=-3.5861034&status=Pauza&usuario=liviudiaconu:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at insert-fichaje.php?lat=40.394548&long=-3.5861034&status=Pauza&usuario=liviudiaconu:14
    at geocoder.js:5
    at geocoder.js:2
    at XS (geocoder.js:2)
    at Kp.d [as o] (geocoder.js:2)
    at Object.c [as _lby7xg] (VM87105 common.js:68)
    at GeocodeService.Search?5m2&1d40.394548&2d-3.5861034&7sUS&9ses-ES&callback=_xdc_._lby7xg&key=AIzaSyBIgTmGmP2ccdBJWMJbH8MYHdxB33tb9AU&token=50596:1
```

Comment: "It's [not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)" is not a clear problem statement. Are errors throw? Does the browser navigate to a new page? Can you see a request being made in the JS console?

Comment: It might help if you provided a [mcve] that demonstrated the problem (rather then some working code and instructions on how to modify it). Your white space is all over the place: Use a code formatter.

Comment: Why do you have PHP in there? Is it relevant to the problem? Remove it and use hard coded strings. See [mcve] again.

Comment: I need php to extract mysql lat and long.

Comment: Please read what I said. You should be able to hard code values for the purposes of a [mcve].

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" — Maybe you should define it then? You are using it: `$.ajax`.

Comment: Quentin, i am added this <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and now is work fine.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added these two lines and now everything works correctly,

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks Quentin for the help.

Comment: **Danger** jQuery 2.x is obsolete and unsupported with likely security vulnerabilities. Use a **current** version of jQuery.

Comment: That won't work. You URLs need to start with `//` (or `http://` or `https://`)

Comment: Don't load multiple versions of jQuery. It's pointless and a waste of resources.

Comment: The second line of code here had an obvious error in it, and wouldn't have worked. I expect it was copied from the comment under the question.